# wordpress multiple search urls

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

So the problem i'm facing is the following:

I have a website with multiple pages where i have to search from. For example: www.example.com/list1 and www.example.com/list2. I also have a global search on the website.

Now I i already got it to work, but the urls say www.example.com/list1/?s=test, www.example.com/list2/?s=test and www.example.com/?s=test.

For this is a dutch website I want to have nice permalinks which have the following urls when I do a search:

```
www.example.com/zoeken/test (the global search)
www.example.com/list1/zoeken/test
www.example.com/list2/zoeken/test
```

I tried adding rewrite rules to the functions.php file, but to be honest I don't really understand the way they work.

```
    add_action('init', 'change_list_rules');
    function change_list_rules()
    {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        add_rewrite_rule(
            "zoeken/([^/]*)",
            'index.php?s=$matches[1]',
            "top"
        );
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
```

Also tried it on .htacces level, unfortunately to no avail as well (Also, doesn't wordpress recreate the entire htacces file from time to time?)

What am I to do to make this work? I'm really stuck here, so a little help would be appreciated!